# android emulator send sms to self with notification using robotium or adb shell

Tags: android, sms, robotium

Iam trying to automate testing an app using robotium. This app gets triggered on receiving sms notification from a particular number. I have all the configurations set for sms originator numbers etc. I have tried the following.

1. using smsmanager api to send sms to self number ( 15555215554), since I do not get notification using this api, my app does not get triggered hence the test fails.
2. using telnet to emulator and send sms works beautifully but cannot telnet using robotium as I assume robotium is running in emulator shell and no telnet is provided. Hence java telnet client is not of much use.

any body knows how to send sms to emulator with sms notification(important) in any other way.